# After converting string to date format month showing different

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-parsing, date

I am converting string to date format year and date showing correct but month showing different.

```
String s = "2018-08-29"
try 
    {

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date parse = formatter.parse(s);

        long time = parse.getTime();

    }catch (ParseException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

output: Mon Jan 29 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2018

Comment: Where is the print statement? show the entire code please

Comment: output is the print statement parse.toString()

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in your format.

`D` stands for day in year, but you need to get day in month with `d`.

This should be like this:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

I hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed it at first. Your date should be simple letters "dd" not "DD" 
DD is day in year
dd is date in month